# Existence of minima between two maxima

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let $x_1,x_2 \in (a,b),x_1<x_2$ be local maxima of the function f, i.e., $\exists \delta_1>0\ such\ that\ \forall x\in\ (x_1-\delta_1,x_1+\delta_1),\ f(x)\leq f(x_1)$ and similarly for $x_2$. Prove that there exists a point of local minima between $x_1$ and $x_2$ ,i.e., $$\exists x_3 \in (x_1,x_2)\,\, \text{such that exists}\,\, \delta_3>0\,\, \text{such that}\,\, \forall x\in\ (x_3-\delta_3,x_3+\delta_3),\ f(x)\geq f(x_3)$$

Comment: Can you use Weierstrass extreme value theorem? This is just a special case of it.

Comment: Thanks, I got my answer. I was adopting a different approach initially trying to pinpoint at least one minima using IVP. The hint was all I needed.Any global minimum on $[x_1,x_2]$ will also be a local minimum. Now I need only prove that the minimum can not be at any of the end points $x_1\ or\ x_2$. This is easily done since otherwise it would contradict the hypotheses that they are maxima unless the function is a constant function in which case any point would be a minimum/maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $x_3\in (x_1 , x_2 ) $ such that $$f(x_3 ) =\inf_{t\in [x_1 , x_2]} f(t) .$$